# How to check the accessibility with Node.js of the raw HTML code, not URI?

Tags: html, node.js, accessibility, pa11y

I need to check the accessibility of HTML code, herewith:

1. I need the Node.js API (class of function), not CLI.
2. I want to pass the HTML string as parameter, not the URI of file path.

Is should be something like:

```js
import AccessibilityInspector from "package-which_i_need";

AccessibilityInspector.inspect({
  rawHTML_Code: `<!doctypehtml><html lang=en><meta charset=utf-8><title>title</title><link href=style.css rel=stylesheet><script src=script.js></script>`,
  standard: "WCAG2AAA"
}).
   then((issues: Array<AccessibilityInspector.Issue>): void => {
     // Log the issues
   }).
   catch((error: unknown) => {
     console.error(error);
   })
```

Below packages does not satisfy to above conditions:

- The [pa11y](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pa11y) accepts only URI as the first parameter, but not the HTML code.
- According the documentation, the [access-sniff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/access-sniff) accepts only URIs too. Although the raw HTML could be also passed, "Pattern is too long" unclear error could occur. Also, the **access-sniff** has many vulnerabilities and not being maintained.

Other options?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Could you focus on a single question? Are you trying a kind of web scrapping?

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear question. Please tell me what exactly you have not understood. My question is single but includes the multiple conditions.

Comment: Maybe try hosting the HTML locally, and then provide the link to localhost to one of those libraries

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine, Thank you for the advice. But why is it too hard to check the accessibility of the raw HTML code?

Comment: What is the input and the expected output?

Comment: @JRichardsz The input is the plain HTML code and nothing more. About output, I am satisfied with [`pa11y` one](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/35a176ac1a07da471ac32ef623b033ae5b819377/types/pa11y/index.d.ts#LL22C24-L22C24), but it could be similar.

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD I honestly don't know why. `pa11y` shouldn't try to make an HTTP request to get HTML code that it already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pa11y` has two modes of operation: get contents from a web page by following the URL, or get contents from the provided `browser` and `page` instances directly, without making an HTTP request. The behavior is controlled by [`ignoreUrl`](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y#ignoreurl-boolean) parameter, which is `false` by default.

## Get contents directly from `browser` and `page`

With the help of `puppeteer`, you can create `browser` and `page` instances and provide them to `pa11y`. You would need to set `ignoreUrl` to `true`:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'
import pa11y from 'pa11y'

// Here comes your raw HTML code
const htmlCode = '<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>'

async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.setContent(htmlCode, {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
  })

  const url = page.url()
  const a11y = await pa11y(url, {
    ignoreUrl: true,
    browser,
    page,
  })

  console.log(a11y)

  await browser.close()
}

main()
```

## Get contents from a local server-hosted web page

Alternatively, you can spin up a local server that would respond to any request with the HTML code, effectively making your own temporary website with the said HTML code.

This can totally be implemented using the built-in `http` module, although it is more cumbersome that way. The below implementation uses `express`:

```
import { type Server } from 'http'
import express = require('express')
import pa11y = require('pa11y')

// Here comes your raw HTML code
const htmlCode = '<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>'

function getPort(server: Server) {
  const address = server.address()!

  if (address instanceof Object) {
    return address.port
  }

  return address.split(':').at(-1)!
}

const server = express()
  .use((req, res) => res.send(htmlCode))
  .listen(async () => {
    const port = getPort(server)
    const a11y = await pa11y(`http://localhost:${port}`)

    console.log(a11y)

    server.close()
  })
```

Note that the server is attached to whatever port is available at the time, which is why we have to use `getPort` function (or similar).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll report once return to accessibility checking task and try your solution.

Comment: Sorry for taking a lot of time. Just tried you solution. Unfortunately the `page.url()` returns the `about:blank`. I you don't know how to deal with it, I'll prepare the new question. By the way... we have not set the URL... Is is being set automatically?

Comment: Indeed, `pa11y` tried to open this URL, even though it can get all data from `browser` and `page`. Weird. Well, all is not lost though. I've updated the answer with another approach, tested it, and it works. Take a look.

Comment: O'K, thank you for your efforts. I have accepted your answer. However, the puppeteer's issue gives me no peace, so I have asked for the help in the [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76536400/4818123).

Comment: Okay, I've missed the crucial `ignoreUrl` parameter. Now it all makes sense. I've returned my previous answer back and added the usage of the parameter there. Regarding the other question, I think it overlaps significantly with this one (especially the answer, which is very similar to the first version of my answer here but with added `ignoreUrl: true` and `browser.close()`). Be careful, because similar questions might cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> Run an accessibility test against a file (absolute paths only, not
> relative):
>
> ```
> pa11y ./path/to/your/file.html
> ```

You can do:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

function run() {
    exec("pa11y ./path/to/your/file.html", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`[ERROR] openCashDrawer: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`[STDERROR] openCashDrawer: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }

    console.log(`openCashDrawer: ${stdout}`); // Output response from the terminal
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but the need the Node.js API (class of function), not the CLI. Would you please to suggest some Node.js API?

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD Pa11y has a JS interface: https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y#javascript-interface

Comment: @JoséLuis The problem is the JS interface not supports the raw HTML code - only URI is available.

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD Could you just save the html to a temporary file, and then use the file as the url to pass to pa11y?

Comment: @JoséLuis Basically it's fine, but I am using the Gulp and the key feature of the Gulp is the avoiding of temporary files.