# Can not get the valid URL from "puppeteer" webpage when create the web-page with custom HTML-code

Tags: puppeteer

In the below code, I am creating the instance of **Puppeteer**'s **Browser**, then creating the new page and set the HTML content. If to invoke the `url` getter-like function, the result will be `"about:blank"`.

```
import Puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import type { Browser, Page } from "puppeteer";

// inside the async function, of course
const browser: Browser= await Puppeteer.launch({ headless: "new" });
const page: Page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setContent(
  "<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>", 
  { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" }
);

console.log(page.url()); // -> "about:blank"
```

I need the valid URL for to use the [pa11y](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pa11y).

From the viewpoint of the logic, I have not set the URL consciously.
At the same time, I have no found the documentation how to do it in this case.
The `newPage` has not the `URL`-like parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `ignoreUrl: true` like written [here](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y#ignoreurl-boolean) and test the puppeteer page with pa11y.

Code : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPGsb.jpg)

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const pa11y = require("pa11y");

const html = `<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setContent(html, {waitUntil : 'domcontentloaded'});

    let url = await page.url();
    console.log(url);

    const results = await pa11y(url, {
        ignoreUrl: true,
        page: page,
        browser: browser,
    });

    console.log(results);
    await browser.close();
})().catch((err) => console.error(err));
```